# Retrieve SocialAccount token and refresh token from django-allauth

Tags: python, django, google-oauth, gmail-api, django-allauth

I am trying to interface with the Gmail API using Django and django-allauth for authentication. I have configured my project according to the [django-allauth documentation for Google](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#google). I am able to log in with a Google account and can see the account details on the Django admin page. Still I am unable to retrieve the token and refresh token to create a `google.oath2.credentials.Credential` object to pass to the Gmail API.

Here is my current attempt:

```py
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialApp, SocialAccount
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

def get_credentials(request):
    app = SocialApp.objects.get(provider='google')
    account = SocialAccount.objects.get(user=request.user)

    user_tokens = account.socialtoken_set.first()

    creds = Credentials(
        token=user_tokens.token,
        refresh_token=user_tokens.refresh_token,
        client_id=app.client_id,
        client_secret=app.client_secret
    )

    return creds
```

However, the `user_token` object is coming back as `None`, so the `account.socialaccount_set` must be empty. I'm not sure how this is possible if the `request.user` is correctly populated (I have verified that it is correct).

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I had to do:

1. Set AUTH_PARAMS['access_type'] to offline for the Google app like so:

```py
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            ...
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'offline',
        }
    },
```

2. And, then do a FULL NEW AUTHENTICATION. Google knows that your account has access to the app and thus only 'nods you by'. Manually revoke the token you see in django admin by visiting the following URL via your web browser:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=ey...
```

3. Connect your Google account anew.

Comment: Thanks. My app has the same issue, and while I'm deploying a Testversion with the access type changed, I need to ask the rationale for 'access_type': 'offline'. 
My understanding may be flawed about 'online' and 'offline'. Can you help me clarify this understanding?

Comment: My understanding is that using 'online' makes sense when you use the provider solely for authentication (because if a token is expired, the user will be prompted to log in and generate a new one). If you use the Google API for fetching additional data while the user is offline, you need a refresh token or else you will not be able to complete the request (as the user is offline and can not log in to refresh the token themselves).

Comment: Is there a way to do this behind the scenes so the user doesnt have to log back in everyday?

Comment: That's accomplished by specifying the offline access_type.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this as well. There is a very specific part of the docs:

https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#django-configuration

> You must set AUTH_PARAMS['access_type'] to offline in order to receive a refresh token on first login and on reauthentication requests (which is needed to refresh authentication tokens in the background, without involving the user’s browser). When unspecified, Google defaults to online.

Have you checked this in your `settings.py`?

Comment: Although it saves the refresh token, django allauth doesnt actually do a refresh, this seems to be manually so a user must re-login everyday. Is that correct?